# Corelocation - didUpdateLocations is never called

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am learning how to get location information on my ios14. However, didUpdateLocations is never called. I have set NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription. When I test this demo on my phone, no prompt jumps out asking my permission of location. I can guarantee my function startGetLocation is called.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Find location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Find location</string>

var myLocationManager: CLLocationManager?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    myLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.myLocationManager?.delegate = self
    self.myLocationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.myLocationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

func startGetLocation() {
    self.myLocationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
    if let currentLocation = locations.last {
        print("Altitude: \(currentLocation.altitude)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try with `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` too? Your code should be working either way...

Comment: where are you call startGetLocation?

Comment: Swift does it automatically when you start to getting location, but you need to add those in your Plist